# Can I say "Nice!" to a "How are you?" greeting?

Tags: greetings

Some friend told me that "Nice!" can't be used as a reply to "How are you?", instead, she suggested "Good!".

Is it really so strict on the word choice in questions like "How are you?"

Comment: There's already a debate over "I'm good" as a response; now "I'm nice" would be the limit. No, you don't say "Nice" in reply.

Comment: I disagree with everyone.. in Australia (at least) "nice" or "noice" is quite a popular colloquialism for "good"/"excellent" and so would be acceptable there as a reply in an informal setting.

Answer (score 1):

Nice, in its most common sense as an adjective means, either

1) Giving pleasure or satisfaction
2) Being kind or generous. Humble.

So when somebody asks you, "How are you?", then would you reply to them, something like this,

"Hi, I am very pleasure giving!" or "I am kind and generous!"

No, right? Hence, it is incorrect to use nice as an answer here. Whereas, fine can also be used to mean, "in good health", which is an appropriate response.